# "http://www." on Uri.TryCreate bug?

Tags: c#, url, uri

I'm getting URL from user and check if this url is valid URL.

First check of the url fails on the input "http://www.":

```
rawUrl = "http://www.";
Uri url;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(rawUrl, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
     throw new InvalidUrlException(inputUrl);
```

In this case, TryCreate() return **true**. Can someone explain me why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "www." part of the URI is a domain name.

A domain name without dots is ambiguous.  For example, does "com" refer to a local server called "com" or the top-level domain "com"?

A trailing dot removes the ambiguity: "com." is the top-level domain.

So `http://www.` refers to the top level domain "www".  It is a valid URI even if this top-level domain doesn't exist yet.  (Though it might exist; I haven't checked.)